# "Your File Type Not Supported" ERROR with PHP Code

Tags: php

I'm building a web app that allows you to upload a file to a webpage and then saves it to local folder.

The problem is that the second `if` statement renders the error `Your File Type Not Supported` even when an accepted file type is uploaded.

The accepted files types are found here: `$allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pdf');`

So I'm not exactly sure why there is an error. I've checked and checked the code for bugs but can't seem to find it.

Here is the html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file">
      <button type="submit" name="submit">Upload File Document</button>

    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the PHP code:

```php
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $file = $_FILES ['file'];
  $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
  $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
  $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
  $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
  $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

  #split name and extension of file
  $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
  $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

  #check for type of files uploaded
  $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pdf');

  if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
    if ($fileError === 0) {
        if ($fileSize < 9000000) {
              #rename uploaded file with unique name
            $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;

              #file destination
            $fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;

              #function to change file location
            move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
            header("Location: index.php?uploadsuccess");

          } else {
              echo "File is too large";
          }
    } else {
        echo "There was an error uploading your file";
    }
  } else {
      echo "Your File Type Not Supported";
  }

}

?>
```

Is it possible that my indentation is off?

Comment: "Is it possible that my indentation is off?"...not in this case no. But a good code editor would show you which brackets belong together, so there's no need for you to have any doubt about that really, if you use the right tools for the job.

Comment: Have you debugged the value of `$fileActualExt` when you run the code, to see if it contains what you expect?

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?  I tested your script on PHP 7.3.11 and did not get an error when using an allowed type, only when using a type not in your array, nothing was actually uploaded however.

Comment: @ShawnW I'm using PHP 7.3.11 (cli)

Comment: please do what @ADyson said. and it is not safe to check allowed type like you do.

Comment: @ali what specifically makes you say it's not safe? If you are going to make statements about security you really ought to explain them for everyone's benefit.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson I'd really like to understand that point as well :P

Comment: Also, looks like there's a 2mb limit on file uploads in the php.ini file. This is why you'll get the error "There was an error uploading your file" error. Not sure how to increase the file size limit.

Comment: @d-dripz you increase the limit by changing the value in the PHP.ini